# How can you deal with BOTH signed and unsigned numbers in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, unsigned, signed

I'm writing a program that needs to work for signed AND unsigned numbers. You take a 32 bit input, first 24 bits is a whole number, last 8 bits is a fraction. Depending on what the fraction is you round up or down. Pretty simple, but how would you write a program that will work whether the input is signed OR unsigned? Do you just make two separate code blocks that execute depending on if a number is unsigned or not?

Comment: What do you really mean by a _signed_ number? A signed number can have a sign, but it need not. To distinguish between signed and unsigned numbers, you will need a separate control signal.

Comment: That sounds like fixed point rather than either signed or unsigned. I'd look at the VHDL-2008 fixed point packages for this.

Comment: When you say "signed or unsigned", might you mean "positive or negative" (not respectively)?

Answer (score 0):

Your program would need to be aware of the source if the data, and from that information derive whether or not the number is signed. Otherwise, how is your program to know whether a vector of bits is (un)signed? Signage is a convention for humans to use to structure data. The hardware you implement just sees a vector of bits.

Answer (score 0):

A 32-bit unsigned number with 8 fraction bits can represent numbers in the range 0 to ((2^32)-1)/256.

A 32-bit signed number with 8 fraction bits can represent numbers in the range -(2^31)/256 to ((2^31)-1)/256.

So, how about converting your 32-bit input (signed or unsigned) to 33-bit signed, which will be able to represent numbers in the range -(2^32)/256 to ((2^32)-1)/256, which will cover your whole range of inputs.

(You have not given any code. In addition to your 32-bit input, there must be some other input to signal whether those 32 bits represent an unsigned or a signed number. You'll need to test that input and do the appropriate conversion based on its state.)